# Searching for the same date in another data frame and adding that associated row's value to the original data frame in R

Tags: r, performance, search, import, processing-efficiency

I want to search through my `importData` for a `Date` and a `Group` that matches with my `OGData`. Once there is a match it would import a `value` into my `OGData`. I was able to do this doing a for loop but I was wondering if there was  function or a way for it to be more efficient because it takes a long time for my loop to check every individual element for the right conditions.

> OGData

| Group | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000-01-01 | NA |
| B | 2000-02-01 | NA |
| A | 2000-04-01 | NA |

> importData

| Group | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | **2000-01-01** | **1** |
| A | 2000-02-01 | 2 |
| A | 2000-03-01 | 3 |
| **A** | **2000-04-01** | **4** |
| B | 2000-01-01 | 5 |
| **B** | **2000-02-01** | **6** |
| B | 2000-03-01 | 7 |
| B | 2000-04-01 | 8 |

Here is my loop for it:

```
OGData <- OGData %>% add_column(value = NA)

for (i in 1:nrow(OGData)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(Temp)){
    if (OGData[i,1] == importData[j,1] & OGData[i,3] == importData[j,3]){
      OGData[i,14] <- importData[j,2]
    }
  }
}
```

It would spit out this:

> OGData

| Group | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000-01-01 | 1 |
| B | 2000-02-01 | 6 |
| A | 2000-04-01 | 4 |

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by creating the data directly in R and sharing that here. Another way is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: You are looking for a "join" -- look that up, many relevant SO answers.